# Web3 how to send ether from client Metamask to contract address native receive function?

Tags: solidity, web3js, remix, metamask

I wonder how can I natively pop-up the MetaMask window to send specific amount of ether as a donation to already defined SC address and ABI?

Short code intro:

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.8.6;
[...]
    receive() external payable minumum_donation_amount(msg.value)  {
        OWNER.transfer(msg.value);
        donated_people[how_many_people_donated+1] = DonatedPeople(msg.sender, block.timestamp, msg.value);
        how_many_people_donated++;
        emit SubscribeDonatedPeople(msg.sender, block.timestamp, msg.value);
    }

    modifier minumum_donation_amount(uint256 amount) {
        require(amount >= 0.0005 ether, "The minumum donation amount is 0.0005 Ether");
        _;
    }
[...]
```

Successfully getting data from SC to JavaScript console with web3 anonymous function like this:

```
(function () {
  CONTRACT.methods.donated_people(1).call().then( function( donated ) { 
    console.log(donated);
  });
})();
```

I can send ether by hard coding the SC address and from/to address. However, I would like to get the ether from contract method directly to native receive function which has modifier to minimum amount. From Remix we are calling "Low level interactions" like this:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas how to achieve the same results in web3 like in Remix? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example works well. Please take a note if you want to hit SC address receive function you have to pass CONTRACT.options.address

```
client_account = accounts[0]; // assuming master client addr

function contribute_to_the_project() {
  const amount = "0.0004"; 
  const amountToSend = web3.utils.toWei(amount, "ether"); // Convert to wei value
  web3.eth.sendTransaction({ 
    from: client_account,
    to: CONTRACT.options.address, 
    value: amountToSend 
  }).then( function(tx) { ;
  console.log("Transaction: ", tx); 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function [`web3.eth.sendTransaction`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-eth.html#sendtransaction) can be used to transfer directly to the contract receive function.

```
web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: USER_ADDRESS, 
    to: CONTRACT_ADDRESS, 
    value: AMOUNT_IN_WEI, 
    gas: GAS_AMOUNT
})
.then(function(receipt){
    ...
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not trigger the receive() func. This just sends from addr to addr.

Comment: @Prologas Why do you say it doesn't work? I've used the same code for many projects under different circumstances from backed, from frontend and it worked every single time.